# Configuration Management Tool in multitenant setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, architecture, multi-tenant

This more of a preliminary and early investigation into best possible solution for a configuration management tool based on certain criteria (use cases described below).

We are more moving towards a multi-tenant architecture and our application will be hosted on AWS, the diagram below shows the possible setup.

[image: Tenant Setup]

Based on the above diagram a tenant could possible have multiple firms in it. I am currently trying to research a configuration management tool that can best serve our needs based on use cases described here

```
 1. The tool must be able to turn features on and off for a tenant and its firms.
 2. The tool must be able to support configurations on per tenant basis and firms basis.
 3. The tool must be able to track changes made to the config.
 4. The tool that can be centralized and that has build once release anywhere capabilities. 
 5. It is possible to have configs split up, in separate tools. For example: application level configs should be separate from feature level configs
```

Based on the above use cases, I was looking at **AWS AppConfig** as a possible solution given its nature of supporting configuration profiles (Feature Flags & FreeForm). Does AppConfig make a good candidate here?

I was looking for feedback on possible alternatives config tools that could support the use cases and be easily integrated into AWS Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

(Full disclosure: I work on AWS AppConfig) Yes - AppConfig is likely a good solution, based on the requirements you have outlined. There are many customers using AppConfig for multi-tenant configurations. AppConfig has configuration deployment-safety guardrails, including config data validation, gradual or instant deployments, and automatic rollback if an alarm goes off during your config update. Considering that the individual tenant data is critical, I would recommend using those safety guardrails.

There are other solutions out there that are good too. But since AppConfig is part of AWS, it has tight integrations with other AWS services that may be useful.

Comment: Thanks @Steve Rice, AppConfig looking like a neat tool for us. What other tools that you think I should look at for analysis needs? I was looking a Consul. but it doesn't come with a validation mechanism.

Comment: Can you advise as to how the configurations are stored for this usecase -  5. It is possible to have configs split up, in separate tools. For example: application level configs should be separate from feature level configs